# Does Express only get data from forms?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I've got an Express `app.post` method that looks like this:

```
app.post('/race', function(req,res) {
  let raceResponse = {
    user_name: req.body.userName
  }
  console.log(raceResponse);
  console.log('Express has received race.');

  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/client/race/index.html'));
});
```

`req.body.userName` is referring to a `div` element in the HTML file from which the process is called. I know that you can get data from forms in this way, using a `name` attribute to get the desired field, but does the same apply to divs and other elements that aren't forms?

It feels messy to create a hidden form and use client-side JavaScript to put the data in there and then get it using Express, so is there any other way of doing this? I've done some Googling but so far, nothing that answers my question has come up.

Comment: please, can you clarify this: `req.body.userName is referring to a div`

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio There's a City page that has a form, which takes you to the Race page, using an `app.post` method. I'm trying to get the data from a `div` inside of the City page, which has the `name` attribute of `userName`.

Comment: How about using GET and query string? like `<a href="/race?name=something">...</a>` and grab it server side like this `var name = req.query.name`

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio That's kind of what I tried to do, but I didn't get anything back when trying to get the data from a div as opposed to from a form.

Comment: `app.get('/race', function(req,res) { var name = req.query.name; ...` notice `app.get`

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio Does this not work with `app.post`?

Comment: Actually it should work on both type GET / POST... If you `console.log(req.query);` is the parameter `name` shown in logs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194237/discussion-between-william-jones-and-graficode-studio).